# Certain numbers within a query field are not recognized in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause

I have a table of studies that includes unique StudiesID, title, abstract, author, subject, etc. I have created a report to help me QC newly entered study data. My coworkers give me a list of the Study IDs they have entered every month and I query the table of >100,000 records like this (additional fields removed for brevity):

```
SELECT QAQC_Studies.StudiesID, QAQC_Studies.NSL, QAQC_Studies.StudyTitle, QAQC_Studies.Abstract, QAQC_Studies.StudyStatus
FROM QAQC_Studies
WHERE [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID]=26806 or 26845 or 100100 or 100110 or 100169
```

The query works fine for studies 26806, 26845, and 100110. But studies 100100 and 100169 don't show up in my query results. I've checked for spaces in those records and they look fine. Almost all of the entries above 100100 don't show up so it is weird that 100110 and also 100111 work fine. Any ideas on what I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

if you want compare a set of values use in

```
  SELECT QAQC_Studies.StudiesID, QAQC_Studies.NSL, 
      QAQC_Studies.StudyTitle, QAQC_Studies.Abstract, QAQC_Studies.StudyStatus
  FROM QAQC_Studies
  WHERE [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID] in (26806, 26845, 100100 , 100110 , 100169)
```

or add the column name to the or condition

```
  SELECT QAQC_Studies.StudiesID, QAQC_Studies.NSL, 
      QAQC_Studies.StudyTitle, QAQC_Studies.Abstract, QAQC_Studies.StudyStatus
  FROM QAQC_Studies
  WHERE [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID] =26806
  OR [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID] = 26845
  OR [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID] = 100100 
  OR [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID] = 100110 
  OR [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID] = 100169
```

Comment: both of your suggestions return the same results I am getting. 26806, 26845, and 100110 are returned, but 100100 and 100169 are not.

Comment: you mean I have a not in my query somewhere? I copy pasted exactly the where statements you wrote. If you mean in the table itself, where would i look for something like that? I don't see any difference between the 100110 row that works and the 100100 row that doesn't work?

Comment: which is the column studiesID data type   ??